# Sending using KafkaTemplate<String, String> returns a exception for using String as a key

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

When using Integer as a key this is not a problem, kafka should be able to handle Strings as a key.

```
ProducerFactory<String, String> pf =
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(senderProps);
KafkaTemplate<String, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
ProducerRecord<String,String> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", "key1","test");
        template.send(pr);`
```

It throws below exception:

> Org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert
>   key of class java.lang.String to class
>   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer specified in
>   key.serializer
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>         at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer.serialize(IntegerSerializer.java:21)
>         at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
>         at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
>         at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:799)
>         at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:784)
>         at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:285)
>         at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:357)
>         at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:206)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems, your Key serializer is set as Integer in ProducerConfig. You need to set the `KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG` as String :

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) had to add StringDeserializer to the DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory aswell. Now it works well !

Comment: Yeah, You need to add in Producer and consumer both whatever key and value type you are using :)  If it helps you, please feel free to accept/upvote the answer :)

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer which solves your problem. It will help others :)